# for-loop issue (how to use i-parameter on the obj name created within the for-loop)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

i'd like to create few Random forest model within a for 
loop in which i move the number of estimators. Train each of them on the same data sample and measure the accuracy of each.
This is my beginning code:

```
r = range(0, 100)
for i in r:
    RF_model_%i = RandomForestClassifier(criterion="entropy", n_estimators=i, oob_score=True)
    RF_model_%i.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_predict =   RF_model_%i.predict(X_test)
    accuracy_%i = accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict)
```

what i like to understand is:

1. how can i put the **i-parameter** on the name of each model (in
   order to recognise them)?
2. after tained and calculated the
       accuracy score each of the **i-models** how can i put the result on
       a list within the for-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
results = [] # init 
r = range(0, 100)
for i in r:
    RF_model_%i = RandomForestClassifier(criterion="entropy", n_estimators=i, oob_score=True)
    RF_model_%i.id = i # dynamically add fields to objects
    RF_model_%i.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_predict =   RF_model_%i.predict(X_test)
    accuracy_%i = accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict)
    results.append(accuracy_%i) # put the result on a list within the for-loop
```

Comment: File "<input>", line 3
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

Comment: where? please share the full code, so it's possible to understand what line you talk about. the code i shared is just your pseudocode with relevant additions

Comment: i runned your code (in your answer above) and pasted the entire error

Comment: the error is referred to this line: `RF_model_%i = RandomForestClassifier(criterion="entropy", n_estimators=i, oob_score=True)`

Comment: ok i runned this code: `r = range(30, 50)
results = [] # init
for i in r:
    RF_model_%i = RandomForestClassifier(criterion="entropy", n_estimators=i, oob_score=True)
    RF_model_%i.id = i # dynamically add fields to objects
    RF_model_%i.fit(X_train, y_train)` and i gave back this error: ` File "<input>", line 4
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`

Comment: it seams ther's a problem with "%" sign, what do you think?